# what do I do with an SIGFPE address in gdb?

Tags: debugging, fortran, gdb

While running an executable in gdb, I encountered the following error:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x08158307 in radtra_ ()
```

How do I understand what line number and file does 0x08158307 without recompiling or otherwise modifying the source? if it helps, the source language was Fortran.

Comment: It is the file which contains `radtra()`, obviously. To find out the line recompile the code for debugging.

Comment: I wanted to know if I could get further information about the address 0x08158307 without recompiling

Comment: You can look at the assembly and guess which line it might be... Good luck.

Comment: You might have some luck with the `addr2line` utility.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I understand what line number and file does 0x08158307 without recompiling or otherwise modifying the source?

That isn't easy. You could use GDB [disassemble](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html) command, look for access to global variables and `CALL` instructions, and make a guess where inside `radtra_` you are. This is harder the larger the routine is, the more optimizations compiler has applied to it, and the fewer calls and global variable accesses are performed.

If you can't guess, your only options are:

1. Rebuild the application adding `-g` flag, but leaving *all* other compile options unmodified, then use `addr2line` to translate the address to line number. (This is how you *should* build the application from the start.)
2. If you can't rebuild the entire application, rebuild just the source containing `radtra_` (again with same flags, but add `-g`). You should be able to match the output from `objdump -d radtra.o` with the output from `disassemble`. Once you have a match, read output from `readelf -wl radtra.o` or `objdump -g radtra.o` to associate code offsets within `radtra_` with source lines that code was generated from.
3. Hire an expert to guess for you. This wouldn't be cheap, as people skilled in this kind of reverse engineering are usually gainfully employed and value their time.

Comment: Great answer. One more question though: What is `disas`?

Comment: @wander95 I've clarified the answer.